# Send Multiple Request To Telegram viaTlsharp

Tags: c#, api, telegram

I have written code to add multiple number to my contact list:

```
     foreach (var item in collection)
            {

  var contacts = new TLVector<TLInputPhoneContact>();
                contacts.lists.Add(new TLInputPhoneContact { first_name = "", last_name = item, phone =  item });


                //Create request 
                var req = new TLRequestImportContacts()
                {
                    contacts = contacts
                };
                await client.SendRequestAsync<TLImportedContacts>(req);
                Thread.Sleep(6000);
            }
```

i have added sleep for adding number to my contact list because telegram api doesnt let me to send multiple request and give me flood error . is there any method to add 50 contact at once ?